# Weird behavior with Graphstream Mouse Listener and Swing JMenuBar

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, jmenubar, graphstream

I'm making a program which creates and displays graphs.

I have a class which handles a graph and implements a mouse listener (`Graphstream ViewerListener`).
In order to grab the events, you need to use a loop and call a pump() method until you're done.

To display the graph, the `Graphstream` library has a View object which extends and can be used as a regular `Jpanel`, just set the View object as a content pane in the `JFrame`.

My class works fine when used with a `JFrame` with no menu bar.

But when i set a `JMenuBar` at the `JFrame`, the problems start.
I call the method inside my graph class, it gets inside the loop, but the `ViewerListener` doesn't work, like it's not listening for events. Why?

This is my class code, unnecessary stuff omitted

```
public class GeneratedGraph implements ViewerListener{  

public String[] getNodes(){
    boolean flag=true;
    startEndNodes[0]=null; startEndNodes[1]=null;
    arrayposition=0;

    while(flag){
        System.out.println("Inside the loop");
        fromViewer.pump();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(250);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(startEndNodes[0]!=null && startEndNodes[1]!=null){
            flag=false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Outside the loop");

    return startEndNodes;
}


public void buttonPushed(String id) {  //This method fires up when you click on a node
    System.out.println("Button pushed on node "+id);

    startEndNodes[arrayposition]=id;
    arrayposition++;

    if(arrayposition>1){ arrayposition=0;}
}
}
```

Now, to put things into perspective, this WORKS, gets in, grabs the nodes, and exits the loop fine. (unnecessary code again omitted)

```
public class main extends implements ActionListener {
public static void main(String args[]){

    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Graph");
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    GeneratedGraph myGraph = new GeneratedGraph(mainFrame);
    myGraph.option1(5,6);  //a method which creates a graph
    myGraph.show();

    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);


    String s[] = myGraph.getNodes();

}
}
```

But when i add this, it doesn't. It just gets inside the loop and events from the `ViewerListener` never fire so it gets stuck.

```
public class main extends implements ActionListener {
public static void main(String args[]){

    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Graph");
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menuBar= new JMenuBar();
    mainFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu algorithmMenu = new JMenu("Algorithms");
    JMenuItem dijkstra = new JMenuItem("Dijkstra");
    dijkstra.addActionListener(this);
    dijkstra.setActionCommand("Dijkstra");
    algorithmMenu.add(dijkstra);

    menuBar.add(algorithmMenu);


    GeneratedGraph myGraph = new GeneratedGraph(mainFrame);
    myGraph.option1(5,6);  //a method which creates a graph
    myGraph.show();

    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);


    String s[] = myGraph.getNodes();

}
}
```

The part that seems to break everything is this
`menuBar.add(algorithmMenu);`
When i comment out this particular line, it works fine.

Any ideas what might be causing the `ViewerListener` not to respond? It just seems so random that a `JMenuBar` would break it.